# Запятые: "Что, когда сделать, и кому, как, о чём говорить"

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Что, когда сделать, и кому, как, о чём говорить" я расставил запятые так, как привёл здесь. Но правильно ли сделал это? Руководствовался исключительно интонацией.

Answer (score 1):

Например: Что, когда сделать и кому, как, о чём говорить - я решаю сам.

Два безличных инфинитивных предложения, соединенных союзом И, запятая не нужна. Но предложение читается с трудом, и его желательно как-то изменить.

В качестве варианта:Что, когда сделать, а также кому, как, о чем говорить - я решаю сам.

Союз А ТАКЖЕ здесь соединительный, он как раз используется при большой распространенности соединяемых частей вместо союза И.

Answer (score 0):

> В предложении "Что, когда сделать, и
> кому, как, о чём говорить" я расставил
> запятые так, как привёл здесь.

Я бы разбил это предложение на два:

***Что, когда сделать? И кому, как, о чём говорить?***

Answer (score 0):

Здесь каждое из слов отвечает на разные вопросы, значит, нет однородных членов. Союз "и" соединяет два безличных предложения, поэтому ни одной запятой здесь не надо

Comment: Нет, не так. Союз "и" при отсутствии запятой может соединять и слова "когда сделать и кому" = "когда и кому сделать".